# How do I add JMenuBar to JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jmenu

I have a `JTextArea`, and I want to add a `JMenuBar` to it, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setBackground(Color.RED);
// ta.setLayout(null); I tried with a null layout and 
                       non-null


pane = new JScrollPane(ta);
pane.setBounds(Main.WIDTH - (Main.WIDTH - 20), Main.HEIGHT - (Main.HEIGHT - 20), Main.WIDTH - 60, Main.HEIGHT - 500);

bar = new JMenuBar();
bar.setBounds(0, 0, ta.getWidth(), 20); // This won't be there if 
                                        // there is a non-null layout.
ta.add(bar); // I also tried pane.add(bar); that didn't work either.
```

Is there any way to add `JMenuBar` to `JTextArea`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the JTextArea into a JScrollPane -- always
2. Add the JScrollPane to the BorderLayout.CENTER position of a JPanel that uses BorderLayout
3. Add the JMenuBar to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START position of the same BorderLayout using JPanel

Done

e.g.,

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(40, 20); // give columns and rows
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(ta);

JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
borderLayoutPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
// add menu's to the menu bar here

borderLayoutPanel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Side notes:

- The code where you call, `ta.getWidth()` is likely returning a width value of 0, since it appears to be called *before* the JTextArea has been rendered.
- You almost *never* want to add components directly to the JTextArea itself as that potentially interferes with the functioning of the text area.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand you correct, you are not adding the JMenuBar to the JTextArea or the JScrollPane, but just adding it to the same position, am I right?

Comment: @nexus: you're adding the JMenuBar just above the scroll pane, and fixed to the scroll pane.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now. Thanks!